# body overflow: hidden don't work in mobile browser

Tags: mobile, touch, overflow

a overflow:hidden body element works well on desktop browsers. but mobile browsers/ touchscreens ignore this behavior.

```
<style>
body {overflow:hidden; height:100%; width:100%;}
.content {height:2000px; width:1000px;}
</style>


<body>
    <div class="content"> long content </div>
</body>
```

I think the problem comes from the touch!? But I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but the way I got around it was using another container inside the body tag that wrapped everything else and put overflow on that. i.e.

```
.siteContainer{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```